Get count of each email type from multiple tables
I have 15+ tables with emails.  I need to count how many emails exist for each internet service provider, like GMAIL, VMG, MSFT, or Other.
Using the below query, I can get a count of the ISPs for one table:
SELECT COUNT(`my_isp`) AS 'COUNT', `my_isp` FROM `table1` GROUP BY `my_isp`

This will spit out something like this:
COUNT | my_isp
---------------
4000  | Gmail
---------------
2000  | MSFT
---------------
10000 | other
---------------
15000 | VMG
---------------

What I need to do is get a total count of the above per each table, and I have over 15 tables.
I'm honestly not exactly sure how to start this.
** EDIT **
All of the tables have the same format with the same columns.  They all look like this:
EMAIL | PROPERTY | STATUS | MY_ISP | CREATED_DATE | OTHER_DATES

Some emails will exist in multiple tables.  The PROPERTY of each table will be different, as well as the STATUS and Date columns (I did not list all of the date columns).
** EDIT 2 **
So I tried to use a UNION ALL like this:
select COUNT(`my_isp`) AS 'COUNT'
from (select count(t1.`my_isp`) from `table1` t1
    UNION ALL
    select count(t2.`my_isp`) from `table2` t2
   ) 

But I get the below error:
#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias


Care to describe or show the definitions for those tables? (If they have the same definitions, why are they separate tables?)

As an aside, UNION ALL will likely be your friend...

I agree they are good candidates for combining into one table, not 15.  That point notwithstanding, what you're probably looking for is a UNION statement.

@erik258 Erm, UNION pays a penalty for deduplication. OP will want UNION ALL

@MatBailie - well, each of the tables have the same columns (EMAIL, PROPERTY MY_ISP, STATUS, etc).  Each table may have emails that exist in other tables (which is something I will need to address in another question).  But they're all the same, but the PROPERTY will be different in each table.  I hope that answers your question.  I'll edit the question to include this information.

If each of the tables have the same columns, you definitely should have built this as ONE TABLE, with an additional column for the provider.

@JoelCoehoorn I can consider condensing down to one table.  The only problem is: that one table might end up being like 25 million records strong, if not more.   Not to mention that one email might exist multiple times. What are your thoughts on that?

Records are records. If you have 25 million, you need server resources to process them  whether in one table or several. Index properly, with the provider first, it won't matter.

If you have duplicates that you need to account for, you really Really should have one table. Then you can take full advantage of a composite index on (my_isp, email)

Without touching on the issue of the correct organization of tables (or one table), you can specify that the error
#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

is caused by the absence of a subquery name.
This is too simple a mistake to discuss)
Actually, the request can be like this.
select my_isp ,sum(cnt) AS total
from (select my_isp,count(t1.`my_isp`) cnt from `table1` t1 group by my_isp
    UNION ALL
    select my_isp,count(t2.`my_isp`) cnt from `table2` t2 group by my_isp
   ) subquery_name
group by my_isp




my_isp
total




google
3


yahoo
2


other
1



fiddle

Looks like all I need to do is keep adding UNION ALL if I want to add additional tables.  Thank you.  I think this solves my problem.

Your union all attempt was close.  You want to return the my_isp from each table.
The "Every derived table must have its own alias" error is telling you that when you select from or join a subquery, you need to give it an alias (as somealias or just somealias after the close paren).
Additionally, you are misunderstanding COUNT; the expression you give to count is only tested to see if it is NULL, and count returns the number of non-nulls for each group; if you omit a group by clause, the group is all the rows.  For this case, you want just count(1) but to also group by and select the my_isp.
So:
select my_isp, count(1) as isp_count
from (
    select my_isp from table1
    union all
    select my_isp from table2
    ...
) as unioned_tables
group by my_isp

It may be more efficient to count within each table and sum them instead:
select my_isp, sum(isp_count) as isp_count
from (
    select my_isp, count(1) as isp_count from table1 group by my_isp
    union all
    select my_isp, count(1) as isp_count from table2 group by my_isp
    ...
) as unioned_table_counts
group by my_isp

